# terraform replace() - Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

When attempting to upgrade to Terraform 0.12 I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid function argument

  on ../../../../../modules/aws/mybox/main.tf line 85, in resource "aws_route53_record" "this":
  85:   name = "ip-${replace(module.this_mybox.private_ip[0], ".", "-")}"
    |----------------
    | module.this_mybox.private_ip[0] is tuple with 1 element

Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required.
```

Looking at the custom module below, I can't seem to use the replace() function in the string...

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "this" {
  name = "ip-${replace(module.this_mybox.private_ip[0], ".", "-")}"
  type = "A"
  zone_id = "${var.dns_zone_id}"
  records = "${module.this_mybox.private_ip[0]}"
  ttl = "600"
}
```

The goal of the module is to spin up an EC2 based on custom parameters. Along with that, there's a few moving parts including adding a private dns record. I've named it based off of this_mybox.private_ip[0]. In Terraform 0.11.14 it worked fine; but I am roadblocked on the upgrade due to this.

Is there another approach for using replace() in the aws_route53_record name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says that `module.this_mybox.private_ip[0]` is a tuple and that is why `replace` fails. This value is also used here `records = "${module.this_mybox.private_ip[0]}"`, which requires a list. We cannot see the value of `module.this_mybox.private_ip[0]` in your question, but based on the error message I would suggest to access the IP address within the tuple with `module.this_mybox.private_ip[0][0]`.

Comment: Referencing the hashicorp terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance code repository, I see that the variable.tf private_ip does not have a string defined. Since the 0.12 update, they've added the line type = string under private_ip.

Now I need to figure out how to fix my remote state file to reflect this change. It is seeing it as tuple? Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You are referencing the output of the module then, where `private_ip` is a list as you can see [here](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ec2-instance/blob/master/outputs.tf#L56). So `module.this_mybox.private_ip[0][0]` should or have you already tried that?

Comment: Hello! I must have made a mistake initially. module.this_mybox.private_ip[0][0] ended up working! Thank you Nicoring!

Comment: Happy to help :)